# Referencing a variable allocated in heap

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I recently picked up C but am a little confused about how we reference something allocated in the heap.

For example, assume we did something as follows:

```
void test(){

    int *a;
    a = (int*)(malloc(sizeof(int)*4));
    a[0] = 1;
    a[1] = 2;
    a[2] = 0;
    a[3] = 0;
}
```

Now, let's say I am in main, obviously, I cannot do something like `a[0]=...` outside the function as there is no reference to `a`, but it is allocated in the heap, so how would I make a reference to it? I am guessing I'd have to return an `int*` or store the address to `a` outside the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am guessing I'd have to return an `int*` or store the address to `a` outside the function.

Yes, that is exactly how it works.

`malloc` allocates a block of memory for you and returns a pointer to the first byte of that memory block.

You must make sure to always keep a pointer to the memory block until you call `free` on it.

This can be done by either returning a pointer to it from the function:

```
int* test(void){
    int *a;
    a = (int*)(malloc(sizeof(int)*4));
    //... (Also check here that malloc didn't return NULL.)
    return a;
}
```

or by storing it somewhere else, e.g. an out-parameter passed to the function or a global variable.

If you leave the function without storing or returning a copy of the pointer anywhere, then you loose the last pointer to the memory block (`a`) and there will be no way to ever reach it again.

This latter situation is known as a *memory leak*.

> store the address to `a`

It should be the address *held by* `a`, not the address *of* `a`. `a`'s value is the address of the allocated memory's first byte. The address of `a` is the address of the pointer variable itself.